# How to Mock asynchronous method which returns Task(Of IList(Of PasswordChangeHistory))

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing

So this is the method I would like to Mock:

```
Function ReturnPasswordHistoryAsync(passwordChangeHistory As PasswordChangeHistory) As Task(Of IList(Of PasswordChangeHistory))
```

And this is my unit test:

```
<TestMethod()> Public Async Function ValidateNewPassword_NewPasswordHasAlreadyBeenUsed_PasswordIsNotValid() As Task
        'Arrange
        Dim newPass = "newPass"
        Dim oldPass = "oldPass"
        Dim confirmPass = newPass
        Dim passwordValid As PasswordValid
        Dim ret As Task(Of IList(Of PasswordChangeHistory))

        'Errors here with null object reference error
        _mockChangePasswordRepo.Setup(Function(x) x.ReturnPasswordHistoryAsync(New PasswordChangeHistory())).Returns(ret)

        'Act
        passwordValid = Await _changePasswordManager.ValidateNewPassword(oldPass, newPass, confirmPass, Nothing)

        'Assert
        Assert.IsFalse(passwordValid.IsValid, "New password and old passord equal one another yet the test passed")
    End Function
```

I believe it is erroring due to the return, but I'm unsure how to mock the return type. Does anyone know how to mock the return type of `Task(Of IList(Of PasswordChangeHistory))`

Comment: looks like you are using Moq. for mocking async return values you can use `ReturnsAsync`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you are using Moq. for mocking async return values you can use `ReturnsAsync`

```
 Dim ret As IList(Of PasswordChangeHistory) = New List(Of PasswordChangeHistory)

 'Setup member to expect any value of PasswordChangeHistory and return a list after an async call
_mockChangePasswordRepo.Setup(Function(x) x.ReturnPasswordHistoryAsync(It.IsAny(Of PasswordChangeHistory))).ReturnsAsync(ret)
```

This will allow the mock to flow through Async/Await calls.

Comment: It was a mixture of my answer and yours. Thanks lad

Answer (score 1):

```
If (results Is Nothing And results.Count > 0) Then
                Return False
        End If
```

Turns out that it's actually this IF statement. Results was `Nothing` and so I thought that the IF would've evaluated the second side and if it returned false, then skipped the second part. But it doesn't, so the count was throwing an exception.

So this is the fix:

```
  If results IsNot Nothing OrElse results.Count = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
```

And - Evaluates both sides

AndElse - One Side then determines is the IF is valid

Similar with Or and OrElse.

Coming from C# to VB is strange, I miss my syntactic sugar